# How to filter unmatched value from ansible variable

Tags: ansible

I have recently upgraded ansible version from `1.7` to `2.0`. After upgrade `with_nested` loop unable to register only matching records in ansible variable. The same is working in `ansible 1.7.2`

Here is example playbook:

```
---

 - hosts: 127.0.0.1
   connection: local

   tasks:

     - shell: "echo {{ item[0] }}"
       with_nested:
         - [{"host": "host1","description": "This is host1 server"}, {"host": "host2","description": "This is host2 server"}]
         - [{"host_name": "host1"},{"host_name": "host2"},{"host_name": "host3"},{"host_name":"host4"}]
       register: all_hosts
       when: item[0].host == item[1].host_name

     - debug: var=all_hosts
```

**Output:**

```
PLAY ***************************************************************************

TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1]

TASK [command] *****************************************************************
changed: [127.0.0.1] => (item=[{u'host': u'host1', u'description': u'This is host1 server'}, {u'host_name': u'host1'}])
skipping: [127.0.0.1] => (item=[{u'host': u'host1', u'description': u'This is host1 server'}, {u'host_name': u'host2'}])
skipping: [127.0.0.1] => (item=[{u'host': u'host1', u'description': u'This is host1 server'}, {u'host_name': u'host3'}])
skipping: [127.0.0.1] => (item=[{u'host': u'host1', u'description': u'This is host1 server'}, {u'host_name': u'host4'}])
skipping: [127.0.0.1] => (item=[{u'host': u'host2', u'description': u'This is host2 server'}, {u'host_name': u'host1'}])
changed: [127.0.0.1] => (item=[{u'host': u'host2', u'description': u'This is host2 server'}, {u'host_name': u'host2'}])
skipping: [127.0.0.1] => (item=[{u'host': u'host2', u'description': u'This is host2 server'}, {u'host_name': u'host3'}])
skipping: [127.0.0.1] => (item=[{u'host': u'host2', u'description': u'This is host2 server'}, {u'host_name': u'host4'}])

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "all_hosts": {
        "changed": true,
        "msg": "All items completed",
        "results": [
            {
                "_ansible_no_log": false,
                "changed": true,
                "cmd": "echo {u'host': u'host1', u'description': u'This is host1 server'}",
                "delta": "0:00:00.005613",
                "end": "2016-04-05 04:09:05.269437",
                "invocation": {
                    "module_args": {
                        "_raw_params": "echo {u'host': u'host1', u'description': u'This is host1 server'}",
                        "_uses_shell": true,
                        "chdir": null,
                        "creates": null,
                        "executable": null,
                        "removes": null,
                        "warn": true
                    },
                    "module_name": "command"
                },
                "item": [
                    {
                        "description": "This is host1 server",
                        "host": "host1"
                    },
                    {
                        "host_name": "host1"
                    }
                ],
                "rc": 0,
                "start": "2016-04-05 04:09:05.263824",
                "stderr": "",
                "stdout": "{uhost: uhost1, udescription: uThis is host1 server}",
                "stdout_lines": [
                    "{uhost: uhost1, udescription: uThis is host1 server}"
                ],
                "warnings": []
            },
            {
                "_ansible_no_log": false,
                "changed": false,
                "item": [
                    {
                        "description": "This is host1 server",
                        "host": "host1"
                    },
                    {
                        "host_name": "host2"
                    }
                ],
                "skip_reason": "Conditional check failed",
                "skipped": true
            },
            {
                "_ansible_no_log": false,
                "changed": false,
                "item": [
                    {
                        "description": "This is host1 server",
                        "host": "host1"
                    },
                    {
                        "host_name": "host3"
                    }
                ],
                "skip_reason": "Conditional check failed",
                "skipped": true
            },
            {
                "_ansible_no_log": false,
                "changed": false,
                "item": [
                    {
                        "description": "This is host1 server",
                        "host": "host1"
                    },
                    {
                        "host_name": "host4"
                    }
                ],
                "skip_reason": "Conditional check failed",
                "skipped": true
            },
            {
                "_ansible_no_log": false,
                "changed": false,
                "item": [
                    {
                        "description": "This is host2 server",
                        "host": "host2"
                    },
                    {
                        "host_name": "host1"
                    }
                ],
                "skip_reason": "Conditional check failed",
                "skipped": true
            },
            {
                "_ansible_no_log": false,
                "changed": true,
                "cmd": "echo {u'host': u'host2', u'description': u'This is host2 server'}",
                "delta": "0:00:00.005463",
                "end": "2016-04-05 04:09:05.425793",
                "invocation": {
                    "module_args": {
                        "_raw_params": "echo {u'host': u'host2', u'description': u'This is host2 server'}",
                        "_uses_shell": true,
                        "chdir": null,
                        "creates": null,
                        "executable": null,
                        "removes": null,
                        "warn": true
                    },
                    "module_name": "command"
                },
                "item": [
                    {
                        "description": "This is host2 server",
                        "host": "host2"
                    },
                    {
                        "host_name": "host2"
                    }
                ],
                "rc": 0,
                "start": "2016-04-05 04:09:05.420330",
                "stderr": "",
                "stdout": "{uhost: uhost2, udescription: uThis is host2 server}",
                "stdout_lines": [
                    "{uhost: uhost2, udescription: uThis is host2 server}"
                ],
                "warnings": []
            },
            {
                "_ansible_no_log": false,
                "changed": false,
                "item": [
                    {
                        "description": "This is host2 server",
                        "host": "host2"
                    },
                    {
                        "host_name": "host3"
                    }
                ],
                "skip_reason": "Conditional check failed",
                "skipped": true
            },
            {
                "_ansible_no_log": false,
                "changed": false,
                "item": [
                    {
                        "description": "This is host2 server",
                        "host": "host2"
                    },
                    {
                        "host_name": "host4"
                    }
                ],
                "skip_reason": "Conditional check failed",
                "skipped": true
            }
        ]
    }
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
127.0.0.1                  : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

In my `all_hosts` its also giving me unmatched record with skip message `"skip_reason": "Conditional check failed"`. I don't want to include unmatched records in `all_hosts` variable.

**Expected Output:**

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "all_hosts": {
        "changed": true,
        "msg": "All items completed",
        "results": [
            {
                "_ansible_no_log": false,
                "changed": true,
                "cmd": "echo {u'host': u'host1', u'description': u'This is host1 server'}",
                "delta": "0:00:00.005613",
                "end": "2016-04-05 04:09:05.269437",
                "invocation": {
                    "module_args": {
                        "_raw_params": "echo {u'host': u'host1', u'description': u'This is host1 server'}",
                        "_uses_shell": true,
                        "chdir": null,
                        "creates": null,
                        "executable": null,
                        "removes": null,
                        "warn": true
                    },
                    "module_name": "command"
                },
                "item": [
                    {
                        "description": "This is host1 server",
                        "host": "host1"
                    },
                    {
                        "host_name": "host1"
                    }
                ],
                "rc": 0,
                "start": "2016-04-05 04:09:05.263824",
                "stderr": "",
                "stdout": "{uhost: uhost1, udescription: uThis is host1 server}",
                "stdout_lines": [
                    "{uhost: uhost1, udescription: uThis is host1 server}"
                ],
                "warnings": []
            },
            {
                "_ansible_no_log": false,
                "changed": true,
                "cmd": "echo {u'host': u'host2', u'description': u'This is host2 server'}",
                "delta": "0:00:00.005463",
                "end": "2016-04-05 04:09:05.425793",
                "invocation": {
                    "module_args": {
                        "_raw_params": "echo {u'host': u'host2', u'description': u'This is host2 server'}",
                        "_uses_shell": true,
                        "chdir": null,
                        "creates": null,
                        "executable": null,
                        "removes": null,
                        "warn": true
                    },
                    "module_name": "command"
                },
                "item": [
                    {
                        "description": "This is host2 server",
                        "host": "host2"
                    },
                    {
                        "host_name": "host2"
                    }
                ],
                "rc": 0,
                "start": "2016-04-05 04:09:05.420330",
                "stderr": "",
                "stdout": "{uhost: uhost2, udescription: uThis is host2 server}",
                "stdout_lines": [
                    "{uhost: uhost2, udescription: uThis is host2 server}"
                ],
                "warnings": []
            }
        ]
    }
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
127.0.0.1                  : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

I am able to filter value using `item|changed` like below

```
 - debug: var={{ item }}
   with_items: all_hosts.results
   when: item|changed
```

But is there any way to exclude these value from variable (`all_hosts`) itself? As its unnecessary increasing the iteration.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, that is the intended behavior. Lot of people have complained about this but avoiding the second loop is not possible.

[Registered Variables](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#registered-variables)

> Note
>
> If a task fails or is skipped, the variable still is registered
> with a failure or skipped status, the only way to avoid registering a
> variable is using tags.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that in official documentation. Thanks for your reply.